# Union of countable set with infinite set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $A$ is infinite and $B$ is countable. I wish to show that $|A \cup B| = |A|$. Clearly $|A \cup B|\geq |A|$. If $B$ is finite, then the rightwards 'shift' function is injective from $|A \cup B| \to |A|$ and hence $|A \cup B| \leq |A|$. (e.g. If $B = \{1, 2\}$ and $A = \{3,4, 5, \dots\}$, let $f(n) = n +2$). But what can  I do if $B$ is countably infinite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint sets.

If $A$ is infinite, then it has a countable subset $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots\}$. And $B$ can be written as $\{b_1,b_2,b_3,\ldots\}$. So, consider the map$$\begin{array}{ccc}A\cup B&\longrightarrow&A\\x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}x&\text{ if }x\in A\setminus\{a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots\}\\a_{2n}&\text{ if }x=a_n\\a_{2n-1}&\text{ if }x=b_n.\end{cases}\end{array}$$